# Проблема с отображением pandas.core.series в pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему pycharm выводит out[81] в виде null - null.
https://github.com/Dmitrysw/studies/blob/master/karpov_intro_ml/intro.ipynb
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можешь версию PyCharm и `pandas` указать?

Comment: @PavelKarateev pycharm 2021.3, pandas 1.4.1, Юпитер сервер развернут через конду

Comment: Спасибо, воспроизвести не получается, но это вроде как известная проблема https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2184. Коллеги подсказывают что это могло быть исправлено в 2022.1 EAP - его можно скачать здесь https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/ поставить параллельно 2021.3 и проверить.

Comment: @PavelKarateev Спасибо, помогло, помечу ваш ответ когда рейтинга хватит голосовать.